# Two dimensional array not firing correctly in console

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am running

```
var spacetime = [];
spacetime.push({
    Title : [], 
    Space : [],
    Time : []
});

  if (doSelect('Location').length > 0 && doSelect('Date').length > 0) {
   for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
      d += dateText[i] + ' ';
    }
    if(location.match(regex)) {
      spacetime[0].Title.push("Hello");
      spacetime[2].Time.push(d);
      });
    }
  };
```

But the console gives me:

```
Cannot read property 'Time' of undefined
```

Yet `d`is fine as it outputs correctly

Comment: Is `spacetime[2] === null` ?

Comment: In the given code you try to access an object at index `2` ( `spacetime[2]`), but you only have one element pushed to `spacetime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pushed only one object to the `spacetime` array, so only the index 0 is "available" to access it. You should `[0]` instead of `[2]` when setting `Time`:

```
var spacetime = [];
spacetime.push({
    Title : [], 
    Space : [],
    Time : []
});

  if (doSelect('Location').length > 0 && doSelect('Date').length > 0) {
   for(var i = 0; i < dateText.length; i++) {
      d += dateText[i] + ' ';
    }
    if(location.match(regex)) {
      spacetime[0].Title.push("Hello");
      spacetime[0].Time.push(d);
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: I see, so basically the other arrays are still considered at index [0] for the main array?

Comment: What is in spacetime[0] is the object that has the arrays as values: {
    Title : [], 
    Space : [],
    Time : []
}

Comment: ok fair enough, i was confusing and considering them as [0], [1], [2].., thanks

Comment: And you can have more objects (each one with three arrays) in that `spacetime` array. For example: spacetime[0].Times.push(...) to set Times array for the first object, and spacetime[2].Title.push(...) to set Titles array for the third object

Comment: so how would I output it now? If I do `console.log(spacetime.toString());` I get `[object Object]`

Comment: I didn't get the `spacetime[2].Title.push(...) to set Titles array for the third object`, what do you mean?

Comment: If we add three objects in `spacetime` (doing something like this for example: `spacetime.push({
    Title : [], 
    Space : [],
    Time : []
}); spacetime.push({
    Title : [], 
    Space : [],
    Time : []
}); spacetime.push({
    Title : [], 
    Space : [],
    Time : []
});`) , we would access the first object (which contains three arrays) by `spacetime[0]`, the second object by `spacetime[1]` and the third one by `spacetime[2]`. Then, if we want to add some value to the array of the third object, we would do: `spacetime[2].Title.push(...)``

Comment: @rob.m to output the array, you can use `JSON.stringnify`: console.log(JSON.stringify(spacetime));